# A silly problem on critical points?

Tags: calculus

> A critical point or stationary point of a differentiable function of a single real variable, $f(x)$, is a value $x_0$ in the domain of $f$ where its derivative is $0$.

Until a few seconds ago, I thought that having a function $f(x)$ and It's derivative $f'(x)$, I'd just need to find points of value zero, that is $f'(x)=0$. But I've tried to do an exercise and find the critical points of $\cos x + 2x$, then having it's derivative: $-\sin x+2$ I've obtained a problem:

The codomain of $(-\sin x)$ is $[-1,1]$, if I add $2$, the codomain becomes $[1,3]$. This might be really silly, but how is it possible that $f'(x)=0$? No points of $f'(x)$ pass through zero.

Reading further:

> A critical value is the image under f of a critical point. These concepts may be visualized through the graph of $f$ at a critical point, the graph has a horizontal tangent and the derivative of the function is zero.

And seeing the graph of $(-\sin x+2)$, I see that there are points in which the slope is zero, but none of them ever touch $y=0$. Is evaluating $f'(x)=0$ necessarily different of finding the critical points?

**EDIT:** From the second quote I've given, in the critical point, the graph has a horizontal tangent and the derivative of the function is zero. The first requirement is made, but Wolfram Alpha actually says that there are critical points:

---

[image]

---

Comment: Hi Jesus. This just shows that the function $\cos x + 2x $ has no critical points.

Comment: @John See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Critical+points++cos+x+%2B+2x).

Comment: I don't understand what is $\sin^{-1}(2)$.....

Comment: @John From the page: "$Sin^{-1}(x)$ is the inverse sine function."

Comment: $\sin x $ is never $2$, so I do not know what is $\sin^{-1}(2)$.

Comment: @John Yes. But the problem is that it seems that it's possible to do some magic and use it. Mathematica solves $\sin(x)=2$ as `{{x -> ConditionalExpression[\[Pi] - ArcSin[2] + 2 \[Pi] C[1], 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[ArcSin[2] + 2 \[Pi] C[1], 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers]}}`.

Comment: There is no magic that will make $\cos x + 2x$ have a critical point.

Comment: @zhw. Then why Wolfram Alpha says there are critical points?

Comment: We are in one real variable as your own post says. There is no real $x$ that is a critical point of $\cos x + 2x.$

Comment: @zhw. So those critical points are complex critical points?

Comment: @JesusChrist yes, since $\sin^{-1}(2)\approx 1.5708+1.3170i$

Comment: I know this is old, but a better definition for $\alpha$ being a critical point of $f$ is if $f$ is not injective in any neighbourhood of $\alpha$.